# Merge State and Props in React

Tags: reactjs

In one of my component I have `this.props.errors` and `this.state.errors`. In this component any one of them is present. I would like to merge them to pass to child component like below.

```
<ChildComponent errors = { this.props.errors/this.state.errors } />
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in spread operator:

```
<ChildComponent errors={{ ...this.props.errors, ...this.state.errors }} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the object [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to merge the keys and create a new object.

```
<ChildComponent errors = { {...this.props.errors, ...this.state.errors} } />
```

Note that the order of the two spreads are important, in the example above keys from the state object will override keys of the same name in the props object.

Edit: If the errors are strings you can either join them or pass them as an array.

```
<ChildComponent errors = { [this.props.errors, this.state.errors] } />
<ChildComponent errors = { this.props.errors + ' ' + this.state.errors } />
```

Comment: Thanks @Avin Kavish for your reply. My `error` code is like below `if (this.state.name === '') {
      this.setState({ errors: 'Atleast Name is required' });
      return false;
    }`. Can I use your code to fetch `errors` ?

Comment: Not in the case that the errors is a string. Do you want to join two strings?

Comment: I would not like to join two strings. I would like to display error message. My error messages are strings. Thanks.

Comment: What? You have to decide how you want to present the two strings. Either in a list or as one string.

Answer (score 1):

you gotta use the spread operator

```
<ChildComponent errors={{ ...this.props.errors, ...this.state.errors }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend the other solutions that are simply using a spread, as they are spreading into a new object each time, which would cause a rerender each time on a PureComponent.

Create an object outside of the render function, e.g. as a class member variable, or state property and populate the errors into that object.

```
class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         allErrors: {
            ...yourStateErrors,
            ...this.props.errors
         }
      }

   }
   ...
   render() {
      <Child errors={this.state.allErrors} />
   }
}
```

Remembering not to just mutate the state.errors property on any further updates